# PWA: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Request failed and no download with file php

Tags: php, progressive-web-apps

I'm tring to do my first **progressive web app** but I'm little confused.

The structure of project is:
- index.php
- products.php
- css/style.css
- css/font/font.eot
- js/script.js
- img/logo.png
- manifest.json
- sw.js

In the folders css and js I have also the files of bootstrap and jquery.
The manifest.json contain:

```
{
"manifest_version": 1,
"version": "1.0.0",
"short_name": "PWA",
"name": "PWA",
"description": "First Progressive Web Application.",
"icons": [
{
"src": "img/512x512.png",
"sizes": "512x512",
"type": "image/png"
},
{
"src": "img/384x384.png",
"sizes": "384x384",
"type": "image/png"
},
{
"src": "img/192x192.png",
"sizes": "192x192",
"type": "image/png"
},
{
"src": "img/152x152.png",
"sizes": "152x152",
"type": "image/png"
},
{
"src": "img/144x144.png",
"sizes": "144x144",
"type": "image/png"
},
{
"src": "img/128x128.png",
"sizes": "128x128",
"type": "image/png"
},
{
"src": "img/96x96.png",
"sizes": "96x96",
"type": "image/png"
},
{
"src": "img/72x72.png",
"sizes": "72x72",
"type": "image/png"
}
],
"start_url": "/", 
"lang": "it-IT",
"background_color": "#424242",
"theme_color": "#cc194b",
"display": "standalone",
"orientation": "portrait-primary"
}
```

The file sw.js contains:

```
// use a cacheName for cache versioning
var cacheName = 'gi-cache';

// during the install phase you usually want to cache static assets
self.addEventListener('install', function(e) {
    // once the SW is installed, go ahead and fetch the resources to make this work offline
    e.waitUntil(
        caches.open(cacheName).then(function(cache) {
            return cache.addAll([
                'index.php',
                'categories.php',

                'js/bootstrap.min.js',
                'js/jquery.fancybox.min.js',
                'js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js',
                'js/jquery-ui.min.js',
                'js/script.js',
                '/manifest.json',

                'css/bootstrap.min.css',
                'css/style.css',
                'css/jquery.fancybox.min.css',
                'css/jquery-ui.min-css',

                'img/logo.png',
                'favicon.ico',
                'img/72x72.png',
                'img/96x96.png',
                'img/128x128.png',
                'img/144x144.png',
                'img/152x152.png',
                'img/192x192.png',
                'img/384x384.png',
                'img/512x512.png',

                'css/font/font.otf',
            ]).then(function() {
                self.skipWaiting();
            });
        })
    );
});

self.addEventListener('activate', function(event) {
      event.waitUntil(
        caches.keys().then(function(cacheNames) {
          return Promise.all(
            cacheNames.map(function(cacheName) {
              if (cacheName.startsWith('pages-cache-') && staticCacheName !== cacheName) {
                return caches.delete(cacheName);
              }
            })
          );
        })
      );
    });

// when the browser fetches a url
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
    // either respond with the cached object or go ahead and fetch the actual url
    event.respondWith(
        caches.match(event.request).then(function(response) {
            if (response) {
                // retrieve from cache
                return response;
            }
            // fetch as normal
            return fetch(event.request);
        })
    );
});
```

In the pages index.php and products.php I have insered also (in the head):

```
<link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#cc194b"/>
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="img/152x152.png">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"> 
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="PWA">
        <meta name="application-name" content="PWA" />
        <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="img/144x144.png"> 
        <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#cc194b">
```

In script.js:

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js').then(function(reg) {
        console.log('Successfully registered service worker', reg);
    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.warn('Error whilst registering service worker', err);
    });
}
```

Obviously it doesn't work beacuse if I put the project in a subdomain with HTTPS I can see the web pages but it doesn't download the PWA.
If I go to the "Application" in chrome, in Manifest I have all the data and a string:

```
No matching service worker detected. You may need to realod the page, or check that the service worker for the current page also controls the start URL from the manifest.
```

The service workers returns "is redundant" and "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Request failed".
So, now, my questions are:
- Is it a problem if I have use a php extension? Can I create a pwa with php?
- Is the procedure corrects? 
- Are the files manifest and sw written correctly?
- Where can be the error?
Thanks

**EDIT:**
The first error is that I included sw.js in the head of index like a normal file javascript. So I have added the code in script.js to include that file. But now the error is "*Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Request failed*"

Comment: This doesn't contain a single line of PHP. So, why the "php" tag and why not a "javascript" tag? Also, incorporate your "EDIT ..." into the question, don't let people piece together what you did from different sections. Lastly, extract and provide a [mcve] and consider that we don't know what you did, neither where and how you clicked in the browse (if you did) and how you serve the code.

Comment: In every tutorial online, I have saw that the extension of principal file is html, but I have used a file php (index.php and not index.html). I have asked if the problem can be the extension beacuse nobody use it. In the php file there is only html code and something like "echo". I have put the parts of code very important that are: manifest.json, sw.js, the header of index.php and the header of script.js. There isn't anything to click, it's like a website so you have to go to index page and stop, I think that if you know the pwa or websites, you should know this steps.

Answer (score 0):

```
"Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Request failed"
```

Always, without exception, points to a misspelled (in cache function of your service worker) or missing file (on the host) in your cache.

I use PHP files. They are written on the server and cached complete in the memory of the browser by the service worker, so yes, you can use PHP. The fun part is trying to use an API offline to make any adjustments. :)

You can use PHP to write your manifest or service worker as long as your .htaccess file supports it.

For Stylesheets, I put this at the top of the file:

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8"); ?>
```

And my .htaccess looks like this (in its own stylesheet directory):

```
<FilesMatch "^.*?style.*?$">
SetHandler php5-script
</FilesMatch>
```

You'll probably want something to address 'js' files or whatever you use.

Answer (score -1):

The whole idea of a PWA is that the resources your web page needs are stored locally. A php file is meant to be executed in PHP, which is a server side language.

If you're running offline, the php file can't be run. Use an html file instead.